# html5 builder deploy to mobile android not working

Tags: android, html, builder

html5 builder deploy to mobile android not working

android deploy error

error message

how to android mobile deploy

i know android target change html5 builder not option

html5 builder into target android deploy option ?

```
Running adb server...
Buildfile: C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

-set-mode-check:
-set-debug-files:
-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\tabago\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Project1
  [gettype] Project Type: Application
-set-debug-mode:
-debug-obfuscation-check:
-pre-build:
-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for Project1...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
[gettarget] API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\bin\rsLibs
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Project1...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'
     [aapt] C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:49: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'
     [aapt] C:\Users\tabago\Documents\HTML5 Builder\project1\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale').
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\tabago\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\tabago\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit AndroidManifest XML File

You are going to want to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file by opening and viewing the source code through a browser. Then you can copy the source code and paste it into notepad or whatever source code editor you prefer. Then eliminate the elements of the code that are causing the error (ex.  No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'). To do this simply eliminate the element of code that contains this text. You can determine the line of code in which the error occurs by looking at number at the end of the error message in HTML5 Builder. You can then match it with the line of code in the source code from the xml file in the browser. Eliminate these elements in the source code editor and save the file as something new. Do this for each of the errors and run again. It should work properly this time.